# Pandas : Finding correct time window

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe  which gets updated every hour with latest hourly data. I have to filter out IDs based upon a threshold, i.e. PR_Rate > 50 and CNT_12571 < 30 for 3 consecutive hours from a lookback period of 5 hours. I was using the below statements to accomplish this:

```
df_thld=df[(df['Date'] > df['Date'].max() - pd.Timedelta(hours=5))& (df.PR_Rate>50) & (df.CNT_12571 < 30)]
df_thld.loc[:,'HR_CNT'] = df_thld.groupby('ID')['Date'].nunique().to_frame('HR_CNT').reset_index() 
df_thld[(df_thld['HR_CNT'] >3]
```

The problem with this approach is that since lookback period requirement is 5 hours, so, this HR_CNT can count any non consecutive hours breaching this critieria.
MY Dataset is as below:
[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ivdna.png)

```
Date               IDs  CT_12571    PR_Rate
16/06/2021 10:00    A1  15      50.487
16/06/2021 11:00    A1  31      40.806
16/06/2021 12:00    A1  25      52.302
16/06/2021 13:00    A1  13      61.45
16/06/2021 14:00    A1  7       73.805
```

In the above Dataframe, threshold was not breached at 1100 hrs, but while counting the hours, 10,12 and 13 as the hours that breached the threshold instead of 12,13,14 as required. Each id may or may not have this critieria breached in a single day. Any idea, How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please excuse me, if I have misinterpreted your problem. As I understand the issues you have a dataframe which is updated hourly.  An example of this dataframe is illustrated below as **df**.  From this dataframe, you want to filter only those rows which satisfy the following two conditions:

1. PR_Rate > 50 and CNT_12571 < 30
2. If and only if the threshold is surpassed for three consecutive hours

Given these assumptions, I would proceed as follows:
df:

```
Date    IDs CT_1257 PR_Rate
0   2021-06-16 10:00:00 A1  15  50.487
1   2021-06-16 12:00:00 A1  31  40.806
2   2021-06-16 14:00:00 A1  25  52.302
3   2021-06-16 15:00:00 A1  13  61.450
4   2021-06-16 16:00:00 A1  7   73.805
```

Note in this dataframe, the only time fr5ame which satisfies the above conditions is the entries for the of 14:00, 15:00 and 16:00.

```
def filterFrame(df, dur, pr_threshold, ct_threshold):
    ff = df[(df['CT_1257']< ct_threshold) & (df['PR_Rate'] >pr_threshold) ].reset_index()
    ml = list(ff.rolling(f'{dur}h', on='Date').count()['IDs'])
    r = len(ml)- 1
    rows= []
    while r >= 0:       
        end = r
        start = None
        if int(ml[r]) < dur:         
            r -= 1
        else:
            k = int(ml[r])
            for i in range(k):
                rows.append(r-i)
            r -= k
    rows =  rows[::-1]
    return ff.filter(items= rows, axis = 0).reset_index()
```

running `filterFrame(df, 3, 50, 30)`  yields:

```
   level_0  index   Date            IDs CT_1257 PR_Rate
    0   1   2   2021-06-16 14:00:00 A1  25  52.302
    1   2   3   2021-06-16 15:00:00 A1  13  61.450
    2   3   4   2021-06-16 16:00:00 A1  7   73.805
```